# mysql real escape string and preg replace with array

Tags: php, mysql

```
function filter($string) {
 $search = array ("'<script[?>]*?>.*?</script>'si",  // Remove javascript.
              "'<[\/\!]*?[^<?>]*?>'si",  // Remove HTML tags.
              "'<>'si",  // Remove HTML tags.
              "'([\r\n])[\s]+'",  // Remove spaces.
              "'&(quot|#34);'i",  // Remove HTML entites.
              "'&(amp|#38);'i",
              "'&(lt|#60);'i",
              "'&(gt|#62);'i",
              "'&(nbsp|#160);'i",
              "'&(iexcl|#161);'i",
              "'&(cent|#162);'i",
              "'&(pound|#163);'i",
              "'&(copy|#169);'i",
              "'&#(\d+);'e");  // Evaluate like PHP.
 $replace = array ("",
               "",
               "\\1",
               "\"",
               "&",
               "<",
               "?>",
               " ",
               chr(161),
               chr(162),
               chr(163),
               chr(169),
               "chr(\\1)");
 return mysql_real_escape_string(preg_replace ($search, $replace, $string));
}
```

I bought some script on internet, and developer is not responding, i fixed everything because a lot of things was deprecated, but i can't fix this.
This is error

> PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/bioskop/public_html/gold-app/gold-includes/GOLD.php on line 72

I tried php version 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0.
NO success.
Please help me upgrade this i'm really new in php.
This code is SOLD and it must worked at some point.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Lordie; use a prepared statement and do away with all that.

Comment: *"I tried php version 5.4, 5.5, 5.6 and 7.0"* << The latter doesn't support `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Not duplicate, I'm using 5.5 php version now. I just said i TRIED others.

Comment: *"How developer could sell this on codecanyon if it is not working"* - you paid for this?? really?

Comment: Yeah I actually did...... 
This was in archive.
I still do not understand, other people are not complaining :(

Comment: That script you "bought", was most likely based on this one http://hornad.fei.tuke.sk/dokumentacie/php/function.preg-replace.html look under *"Example 3. Convert HTML to text"* and https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~pbrandao/aulas/0203/bdm/docs/php_pt/function.preg-replace.html

Comment: On site it is stated it supports php 5.3, 5.4, 5.5

Comment: Many answers, none says how to fix code.
This is amazing :D

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the $string parameter is an array. If you read the manual page for preg_replace, you'll come across the following:

> preg_replace() returns an array if the subject parameter is an array,
>   or a string otherwise.

The question is: Why is this filter function being given an array when it expects a string?

Comment: I know it's an array, how to change the code? What should i do?
How developer could sell this on codecanyon if it is not working.
Explain please

Comment: Where is the filter function called? Is it called in one place or is it present throughout the code?

Comment: I found it!
$title = filter(htmlspecialchars_decode($_REQUEST['API_TITLE']));
   $year = filter(htmlspecialchars_decode($_REQUEST['API_YEAR']));

 $category_id = filter($_POST['genre']);
  $movie_flv = filter($_POST['movie_flv']);
  $movie_iframe = filter($_POST['movie_iframe']);
  $post_title = filter($_POST['title']);
  $year = filter($_POST['year']);
  $imdb = filter($_POST['imdb']);
  $directed_by = filter($_POST['directed_by']);
  $casts = filter($_POST['casts']);
Theres a lto of it

Comment: You'll need to find out by doing a full search. I can tell you how to fix the error, but fixing it may create even more errors.

Comment: please just tell me how to fix it please

Comment: Are you sure that's the only piece of code that uses the filter function?

Comment: these are all FILTER callings i have.

Comment: Is there a checkbox in your form?

Comment: What is the name of your checkbox field?

Comment: Choose movie genre, and then you choose genre, comedy etc